# Keep Grid center and minimize/maximize on stretching in a WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, grid, alignment, stackpanel

> 

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="0,0,100,0"           
            Grid.RowSpan="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Height="80" Width="30" 
            Background="blue">
            <!--<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition   Height="Auto"/>                   
                    <RowDefinition   Height="Auto"/>[![enter image description here][1]][1]                   
                    <RowDefinition   Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <Button
                x:Name="Add"
                Width="25"
                Height="25"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Margin="3,1,3,0"                   
                Padding="0"/>                   
            </Grid>-->
        </Button>
        <Grid
            Margin="0,0,0,100"
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Width="50" Height="25" 
            Background="Red">
            <Button
                x:Name="Add1"
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Margin="3,1,3,0"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="Remove1"
                Width="20"
                Height="20"               
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="0" 
               Grid.Column="1"                
               Grid.RowSpan="3" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"    
               Width="100" 
               Height="50"
               Background="Green">
            <!--<Button
                x:Name="Add2"
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Margin="3,1,3,0"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="Remove2"
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Margin="3,1,3,0"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />-->
        </Grid>
        
        <!--Element #-->
        <Grid  Margin="0,0,0,100"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="100" Height="25" 
                    Background="Red">
            <!--<Button       
                Name="myButton"
                IsEnabled="False"
                Background="#C0C0C0"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Width="25"
                Height="25"/>-->
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Is there any possibility to keep all the elements center and stretched to the right when maximize? Every container from Grid can have 3 or 4 children's. Children's can be any container as long as all elements are stretching to right and down but maintained center position.
I attached also the result. All elements are centered but the stretching is missing.
What kind of container is suitable for this situations?
[image]

Comment: You can use Border instead of Grid for the children, it expands as the its context expands. Side note: If you set fixed Height and/or Width it will not expand either way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as o_w mentioned in the comment, a good solution is to use `Border`. Where you use your child Grids, encapsulate them in a Border and set the `Background`-property on the Border instead of the Grid. You will see that you will achieve way faster what you want.

The problem you describe is actually something I also struggled with in the beginning, and that's when I found that not only `Grid`, but the combination of `Grid` and `Borders` (with a `Grid` encapsulated in it) is even more powerful than Grid alone.